# Compare using File.lastmodified in java

Tags: java, file

I need to compare the last modified time stamps from two locations. If they dont match, I need to copy file from first location to second and also set the modified time stamp of second with that of the first.

I am trying this with File.lastModified in java. But I am getting different values of File.lastModified for the same file at different times even though they are not being modified. Please note that am trying this in linux.

Can anyone point whats going wrong ?

Thanks

Copying the code :

```
/**
 * Copies files from Source to Destination Directory
 *
 * @param src Source Directory
 * @param destFolder Destination Directory
 * @param existingROOTNames Existing ROOT files
 * @return boolean flag to indicate whether root context has changed
 */
private static boolean copyFiles(File src, File destFolder, String[] existingROOTNames) {
    final String[] fileNames = src.list();
    boolean changeRootContext = false;
    File srcFile = null;
    File destFile = null;
    List rootFileList = Arrays.asList(existingROOTNames);
    int rootFileIndex = -1;
    long srcFileTime;
    long destFileTime;
    for (int index = 0; index < fileNames.length; index++) {

        srcFile = new File(src, fileNames[index]);
        destFile = new File(destFolder.getPath(),fileNames[index]);

        if (srcFile.isFile()) {
            if (log.isEnabled(DEBUG)) {
                log.debug("copy file : " + srcFile);
            }
            srcFileTime = srcFile.lastModified();
            destFileTime = destFile.lastModified();
            if(hasFileChanged(srcFileTime,destFileTime)){
                changeRootContext = true;
                if (log.isEnabled(XDEBUG)) {
                    log.debug(XDEBUG,"changing flag to true for : " + srcFile);
                    log.debug(XDEBUG,"changing flag srcFile.lastModified() : " + srcFileTime);
                    log.debug(XDEBUG,"changing flag destFile.lastModified() : " + destFileTime);
            }
            }
            try {
                FileUtil.fastChannelCopy(srcFile.getPath(), destFolder.getPath());
                log.debug("changing flag while modifying destFile.lastModified() : " + destFile.setLastModified(srcFileTime));
                log.debug("changing flag after modifying destFile.lastModified() : " + destFile.lastModified());
                rootFileIndex = rootFileList.indexOf(fileNames[index]);
                if(rootFileIndex!=-1){
                    existingROOTNames[rootFileIndex]=null;
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.debug("unable to copy source file : "
                        + fileNames[index], e);
            }
        }
    }
    return changeRootContext;
}


/**
 * Checks whether the provided timestamp matches or not
 * This is required as in linux the time is approximated to nearest milliseconds
 *
 * @param srcFileTime
 * @param destFileTime
 * @return whether matched or not
 */
private static boolean hasFileChanged(long srcFileTime, long destFileTime){
    return Math.abs(srcFileTime-destFileTime) > 1000l;
}
```

Comment: Can you print out the timestamps with milli-seconds to see if they match the timestamp of the file in `ls -l`?

Comment: The ls -l option in linux is showing it in proper date format like :-rw-rw-r--  1 uccxuser uccxservice 3362 Dec  7 23:50 /opt/cisco/uccx/Documents/User/default/webapps/ROOT/cc.txt. I am printing the long value returned by File.lastModified in my program and seeing that its returning different values everytime. Some example :changing flag srcFile.lastModified() : 1323282046000
changing flag srcFile.lastModified() : 1323772334000
changing flag srcFile.lastModified() : 1323282046000

Comment: also what does  stat -c %Y filename print?

Comment: Changing the flag appears to change the last modified date.  Can you reset the last modified date after change the flag?

Comment: @soulcheck stat -c %Y filename prints : 1323282046 This is consistent with the output I get sometimes as : 1323282046000 with some zeros appended at the end. Do you think executing this command from my program will be better way to check the files last modified timestamp than the java api ?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey the flag is just a local variable which I set if I think that the file is modified. It is used later on for some other purpose.

Comment: It's the FileUtil.fastChannelCopy() function property closing the underlying streams? Have you tried doing a raw copy or using another library like org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils?

Answer (score 1):

Can you be sure that there are not processes accessing the file?
Try with fuser -k /path/to/your/filename to kill any process that could be accessing the test files.

Comment: I tried fuser -i so that it will ask me the option to kill process if any. But no luck there as well. [root@dactyl-esx-sa ~]# fuser-i /opt/cisco/uccx/Documents/User/default/webapps/ROOT/cc.txt [root@dactyl-esx-sa ~]#